# The DropDown Menu in navbar is bounded by the size of Navbar in React nav dropdown reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am following this example
[enter link description here](https://6-4-0--reactstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/)

My navbar was like :

```
 <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
    <DropdownToggle caret>
      Dropdown Test
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownItem disabled>Action</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem divider />
      <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
  </Dropdown>
```

however the dropdown menu in navbar is bounded by the size of navbar, how can it overwrite it?
[image]

[image]

i dont want to adjust the header css like

```
ul {
height:10rem 
}
```

to make it works thanks

Edit the code i am working in jsx:
is too long to upload here ,

this is the code i move to the codesandbox
[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-smoke-nyorh)

Thanks

Jeff

Comment: Do you want to change the height or width?

Comment: @BadalSaibo no i dont want to change the height or width

Comment: For me it looks like its a css issue rather then a react. Its if the actual dropdown wouldint have `position: absolute` or something else. Try stripping away your css and see if this issue fixes it. If it dosent, it would help to get more of the code to see what could effect it. Best solution would post a live demo on codesandbox.io, or similar site, or just update your post with more code.

Comment: how can i use the "Properties" in the reference , i try adding it to CSS but it cause error

Comment: @Lith i upload to the code-sandbox thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some time but figured it out. I was right, the issue is css. I fixed the issue in this forked project of yours https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-mendeleev-n1709?file=/src/Dashboard.css

The reactstrap is dependent on bootstrap https://reactstrap.github.io/ Simply install bootstrap via `npm install --save bootstrap` and import it in the main `injex.js` file cia `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` fixes majority of the issues.

In addition, removed a lot of your own written css as it was either a) incorrect or b) no longer useful.

**The other issues**

The reason the header hight was to high because you used `height: 5rem` on `ul` element.

The reason drop down menu was hidden was because of the `overflow: hidden` on the `ul` element.

Comment: thanks . i guess the overflow:hidden was already solved my problem , and i wanna ask if i still need to install the bootstrap library/module ? and why ? thanks you

Comment: @ManManYu Your welcome. Yes, I would recomend installing the boostrap module. Altho you do not have to but assuming you are using reactstrap so it would increase your productivity time without neeing to create every single component yourself. well in that case, those components already going to have css to startt with styles as default. That way if you wish to change some such as `color` `width` `font` and so on - you may just override with your own css. but the rest such as `float` `position` and so on, the css that HAS to be there, will be already written